# Java equivalent of Smalltalk's become:

Tags: java, design-patterns, smalltalk

Is there a way to swap myself (this) with some other object in Java?

In Smalltalk we could write

```
Object subclass:myClass [
    "in my method I swap myself with someone else"
    swapWith:anObject [
        self become:anObject.
        ^nil
    ]
]

myClass subclass:subClass [
]

obj := myClass new.
obj swapWith:subClass new.
obj inspect.
```

Result is `An instance of subClass`, obviously.

I need to do following in Java:

- I am in a one-directional hierarchy (directed acyclic graph)
- in one of my methods (event listener method to be exact) I decide that I am not the best suited object to be here, so:
- I create a new object (from a subclass of my class to be exact), swap myself with him, and let myself to be garbage-collected in near future

So, in short, how can I achieve in Java `self become: (someClass new:someParameters)`? Are there some known design patterns I could use?

Comment: I'd add a level of indirection. A container object that can swap objects implementing the desired interface.

Comment: Not in the same way as in Smalltalk. Using a simple container would be the easiest, e.g., a wrapper that delegates to the "real" object, or put the substitution logic into the DAG class itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In its most general form, arbitrary *object swapping* is impossible to reconcile with static typing. The two objects might have different interfaces, so this could compromise type safety. If you impose constraints on how objects can be swapped, such a feature can be made type safe. Such feature never became mainstream, but have been investigated in research. Look for instead at [Gilgul](http://www.dsg.cs.tcd.ie/~sclarke/05-costanza.pdf).

Closely related is *reclassification*, the ability to change the class of an object dynamically. This is possible in Smalltalk with some primitives. Again, this puts type safety at risks, never became mainstream, but has been investigated in research. Look at [Wide Classes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48743-3_18), [Fickle](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45337-7_8), or [Plaid](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/papers/plaid-oopsla11.pdf).

A poor man's solution to object swapping is a *proxy* that you interpose between the client and the object to swap, or the use of the state and strategy design patterns.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.java.net//node/644225) is an interesting thread on the official forum. I believe that object encapuslation in combination with strong types makes this function unable to work in Java. Plus for already slow JVM, this could lead to disaster...

Comment: Thanks, quite interesting thread. Easy proxy pattern (like in Smalltalk by overloading #doesNotUnderstand) would be nice for this case instead of become:.

Answer (score -1):

`this` is a reserved word in Java and you cannot override it.

What you're trying to do can be implemented with a simple reference. You just iterate (or go through your graph) and change pointer to what you want to be active.

Consider this:

```
 List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
 // fill your list

 String longestWord = "";
 for (String s : stringList) {
     if (longestWord.length() < s.length()) {
         longestWord = s;
     }
 }
```

`longestWord` is poiniting to another object now.

Comment: The function become does not change pointers, it changes the object itself. You don't lose the old object by calling become. Thus, you fetch some data first, then you change its identity without any data loss...here you just...rewrite.

Comment: It should be `reference` instead of `pointer`. Java doesn't have pointers.

Comment: This is Java and it works this way. Also author said: `I create a new object (from a subclass of my class to be exact), swap myself with him, and let myself to be garbage-collected in near future`

Comment: Sure, reference, sorry (too much Objective-C lately). Sure to swap objects, this is great example. I felt like there was need for the actual become: function, in which case...without proper memory management this could be using a lot of memory..

Comment: become: does not simply do _(pseudo-code)_ `tmp := self. self := other. other := tmp.` The going through whole graph is something that cannot be done, since inside the method I don't have access to hierarchy head (graph is directed, only one way to go).